# How to combine two inputs into one value and bind?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use 2 Inputs to define an age. Both values should be passed to a new input which is alread binded to *rule.data*. Is that possible? I'm new with angularjs and probably I have a flaw. Thanks for your tips

**HTML**

```
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-model="age.from"/>
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-model="age.to"/>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rule.data" value="between {{age.from}} and {{age.to}}" />
```

Comment: did you try fixing the typo 'ng-mdodel' in first 2 inputs: ng-mdodel="age.to" -> ng-model="age.to" ?

Comment: @shershen, thank you it was a copy paste issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not really understand why you want to use an `<input>` to format a text with the values of min and max.

You would rather do this, no ?

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-model="age.from"/>
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-mdodel="age.to"/>
<span>between {{age.from}} and {{age.to}}</span>
```

Does this work for you ?

---

If the string is just a placeholder for the user age value, you should do this instead :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-model="age.from"/>
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-mdodel="age.to"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rule.data" placeholder="between {{age.from}} and {{age.to}}" />
```

---

If you need to get the final string into the model, you can do something like this then:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-model="age.from"/>
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" min="1" max="110" ng-mdodel="age.to"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rule.data" ng-init="rule.data = 'between ' + age.from + ' and ' + age.to" />
```

(I assume you do not have a controller to initialize the model properly. 
If you do, then just add this kind of line inside : `$scope.rule.data = 'between ' + $scope.age.from + ' and ' + $scope.age.to;`. it should do the trick.)

Comment: I need the binding 'rule.data'

Comment: And what kind of value do you want bind to `rule.data` ?

Comment: age.from and age.to should binded to new value rule.data

Comment: A placeholder is a bad solution, sorry. The third input expect a defined "query" , e.g. 'between 10 an 40'. Later I will hide this input. I use it only as an helper input

Answer (score 1):

can vary with many solutions, you can add a custom filter at third combined result ,

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rule.data | customFilter:age.from:age.to" value="between {{age.from}} and {{age.to}}" />

    app.filter('customFilter',function(){
    return function(input ,fromage,toage){
       //your code for between
        return //your calculated age
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'rule.data | customFilter:age.from:age.to' is non-assignable

Comment: can you provide fiiddle then i can help u in a better way.